# Alert appears before click or event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this line in my React Native app :

```
   <Image onPress={alert('Image')} source={require('./assets/home.png')} />
```

I want it to show an alert after clicking on the image, the problem is the alert appears after the login without even clicking on the Image or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, and as you've found, your function will be called immediately. To get the interaction you want you need to use the following

`<Image onPress={() => alert('Image')} source={require('./assets/home.png')} />`